# Why are the stack memory locations not reused by parallel blocks?

Tags: c, gcc, stack

I know that GNU CC has a very complex variable allocation mechanism. However, I want to understand the reason behind the following strange behavior.

Using `gdb` I debugged the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int a, b;
  { /* bl1 */
    int a1 = 101, b1 = 201;
    a = a1; b = b1;
  }
  printf ("%d %d\n", a, b);
  { /* bl2 */
    int a2 = 102, b2 = 202;
    a = a2; b = b2;
  }
  printf ("%d %d\n", a, b);
  { /* bl3 */
    int a3 = 103, b3 = 203;
    a = a3; b = b3;
  }
  printf ("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

The memory locations for all the local variables are like this (only the last two hex digits of the memory addresses are given below, since the digits indicated with `...` are identical):

```
-/* bl3 */
b3 ...5c
a3 ...58
-/* bl2 */
b2 ...54
a2 ...50
-/* main */
b  ...4c
a  ...48
-/* bl1 */
b1 ...44
a1 ...40
```

As you see,

1. Variables for `bl1` are assigned *below* variables for `main`, while the variables for the other two blocks are assigned *above*.
2. Variables for `bl2` and `bl3` do *not* reuse the empty stack space left over `bl1` and `bl1` and `bl2` respectively.

The program was compiled with the single option `-g`, because option combinations like `-Og -g`, `-O3 -g`, or `-Os -g` did not allow me to set breakpoints into the inner blocks.

Comment: Be careful, using uninitialized variables and their indeterminate value can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: `-O0` just generates “dumb” assembly code. It does not attempt to reuse stack or be efficient. Use `-O3` or `-Os`. And use a sample program that has behavior that is both defined and observable.

Comment: How about [this](https://godbolt.org/z/b49fM13j9)?

Comment: `hile the variables for the other two blocks are assigned above.` Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes and remember that on x86 `The stack grows toward numerically lower addresses`.

Comment: Thanks @ssbssa. I had already noticed (before posting the question) that adding `printf` statements (to display the variables' addresses)  changes the compiler's behavior. And in my system (Ubuntu 21.04, gcc 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) the compiler behaved _as I had expected_ even for **any type of optimization option**.

Comment: Wait, if on your system the compiler always behaves es you expected, then what's your question again?

Comment: It doesn't behave "as expected" in the scenario I described in my question (with no `printf` statements to display the variables' addresses)! :) In the above example, if I remove the initializations for variables `a3` and `b3` in `bl3`, the last `printf` should display `102 202`, but it does not. (Of course, you may say that using uninitialized variables is a typical "undefined behavior" for a program!)

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the stack memory locations not reused by parallel blocks?

Because you compiled with disabled optimizations, which literally means that an optimization that reuses memory locations is disabled.

Comment: Can you comment on which optimization is that please?

Comment: No I cannot. here's a list: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html